# Add horizontal space in a figure with three subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats, plot

I have a figure with three subfigures arranged in two lines. The first one contains the first two subfigures. The other one contains the third. I would like to increase the horizontal spacing between the last one and the other two. The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{geometry}
        \geometry{ 
            bottom=2cm,
            left=2cm,
            right=2cm,
            top=2cm
        }
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]\centering
        \setlength\belowcaptionskip{-1.5ex}
          \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}\hfill
             \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
            \end{subfigure}
             \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
                \caption{}
            \end{subfigure} 
            \caption{ }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wlcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document with your figure beginning with `\documentclass` and ended by `\end{document}`.

Comment: Last subfigure is horizontally centered. Where you like to add horizontal space? Or you mean vertical space between rows between images?

Comment: I would like the two rows to be more separated so the purpose is to add more horizontal space between them, i.e., place image C lower

Comment: Like as shown in my answer below?

Comment: Thank you, it was solved by the [belowskip=2ex] command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessing, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[belowskip=2ex]{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[ht]\centering
%        \setlength\belowcaptionskip{-1.5ex}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Riemananalitic0.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:nperiodic1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Riemananalitic10.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:nperiodic2}
\end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Riemananalytic100.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:npdiflog}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{MY figure with three subfigures}
\label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```